# odata v4 - pass multiple parameters

Tags: c#, api, odata

I need to pass these parameters to an odata endpoint:

- id
- year
- person [type of Person]

I tried with two parameters first, but it is not working. This is what I am getting:

```
The path template 'People({id}, {year})' on the action 'Get' in controller 'People' is not a valid OData path template. The number of keys specified in the URI does not match number of key properties for the resource
```

---

```
public class PeopleController : ODataController
    {

     [EnableQuery]
            [ODataRoute("People({id}, {year})")]
    
            public IHttpActionResult Get([FromODataUri] int id, [FromODataUri] int year)
            {
    
            }
    }



 public class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
           
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTimeOffset DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I pass multiple parameters and especially these:

```
id : int
year : int
person : [type of Person]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create another DTO which will contain these properties:

Eg:

```
public class PersonInfo {
   public int id {get;set;}
   public year int {get;set;}
   public Person person {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your controller set it as follows:

```
 public IHttpActionResult Get(PersonInfo info)
 {
    //your gode here
 }
```